# Yii relation returns null on Linux

Tags: linux, yii-relations

I'm facing with a strange problem. I made an application on Windows, and I'm trying to deploy it to Linux. I know about the case problems, and corrected it where I could, but this time I don't know what to do.

I have the following model:

```php
public function relations()
{
    $tmp=parent::relations();
    $tmp['applied_teams']=array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Group',     'qualification(group_id,competition_id)');
    $tmp['rounds'] = array(self::MANY_MANY,     'Competition','competitions_competitions(competition_parent,competition_child)');
    return $tmp;
}
```

where applied_teams returns null, but rounds not. The records are correctly in the database. Do you have any idea what would make difference in it between these two operating systems?

**UPDATE**

I've written a workaround, but haven't find the reason of the problem. The getter method has no problem on linux:

```php
public function getAppliedTeams() {
        $qs = Qualification::model()->findAll('competition_id=:c', array(':c' => $this->competition_id));
        if ($qs == null) {
            return null;
        }
        $results = array();
        foreach ($qs as $q) {
            $results[] = $q->group;
        }
        return $results;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the MySQL engine. Server's default was MyISAM, not InnoDB, but foreign key creation did not threw exception ..